# Want to pass ArrayList contain class objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have a ArrayList which contain objects of a Java Class.I want to pass that list to javascript and want to populate the data within the object in to jsp.
The ArrayList is present in the jsp.Each class object only contain 2 parameter values.Class name is 'Certificate' and it contain 'certId' and 'certName'

jsp:

```
<% 
 ArrayList getAllCertificateNamewithId=new ArrayList();
 getAllCertificateNamewithId=(ArrayList)mainMap.get("getAllCertificateNamewithIdMap");%>
<input type="button"  width="16" height="16"  onclick="fetchAndShow('<%=getAllCertificateNamewithId %>')" />
```

Javascript

```
function fetchAndShow(certObj){
//How to fetch the list's each object  and cast to java class 'Certificate'
}
```

List contain

```
[com.dto.Certificate@9b44a1, com.dto.Certificate@1b6b3ac]
```

Answer (score 2):

Think of it this way: you use Java + JSP as a means to write a text file that you then send to the user's browser, with JSP being a simple template mechanism.

You could theory implement your own method to serialize the List with objects to a String, and then implement a mechanism on the client side to deserialize into whatever data structure you want. For instance you could write your List as JSON.

But now I am inclined to ask: do you really, really, Really, **REALLY** need to do this ? Exposing server certificates of any kind to the client is a big no-no.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the correct way. Just because of the contents are in the same page, they can't communicate directly.

Java plays on server side and javascript on server side. A client doesn't execute the java code.

To send a Java value to javascript you have to make a server request, So the server process your request and send the results back to Javascript.

Inshort  you need to make a server (AJAX) request.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it would be right or not but it's worth a try. Try to use GSON or JACKSON libraries to convert your java object to JSON string. Then I think that you would be able to use that JSON String data in your Javascript code and get the certID and certName wherever you want.